# Installing python package with private.txt doesn't work

Tags: python, openedx

I've installed OpenEDX devstack ironwood release using docker on my computer and works correctly. Now I'm trying to install some additional python packages using the lms/requirements/edx/private.txt file. From my understanding, any package that I add to that file should be automatically installed when I after running the make dev.provision command, but the package is not installed.

If I try to install the package manually using the pip install command from inside the container, the package is installed correctly. But this is not a solution, because as soon as I restart the container, the package is "gone".

So my question is, How can I install additional packages in an openEDX devstack deployment?

Answer (score 0):

During `make dev.up` the [script](https://github.com/edx/devstack/blob/master/Makefile#L112) runs `programs/provision.sh`.
You could add in that provision.sh something like

```
command="source /edx/app/edxapp/devstack.sh && cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform && pip install -r requirements/edx/private.txt"
docker exec -i edx.devstack.lms bash -c "${command}"
```

after `provision_ida lms "lms shell" edxapp edx-platform`. Or something fancier to that effect.

Now, a better practice would be to commit your docker image after you have installed your private requirements. For this you can use:

```
docker ps | grep devstack.lms  # get the CONTAINER_ID
docker commit <CONTAINER_ID> edx.devstack.lms
```